# React Native fetch, unexpected token

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to call a simple REST service with **fetch api** in **React Native**. I'm running the app on **Android**.

When I call `await response.json()` I get

> Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

, I tried also with `await response.text()`, and I get this text as result:

> ��Mn�0��B�[C�bn�u��?@�+�bLR�ҌBR.�
>   �����H�ծ�͛�#?>�g���t�%{���Z��؄u�>fs0`]����H��'&��u�Z}��y�Z��2����i�d�G�>����R����6LL{j�j�7\���������d���L.���gٲXv�Lf��g�%T�~�\z�U8E܀���ڭ�c��@[G�;�T�������{�*�9�)��a½
>   ���0�组V:ϒ���/�K��3�ݝ����W:    c�^UV@�B�7�@�v
>     �+WG��@YL�|Ġ>q�=@�J}�3=��Q�]Հup^E�0 ^d'Ա
>   �^���b�.��2,м���g2��R<���_rpV:!��<��^>�����{�e�#7m���nA�;n�������l�o�u��kW���r`���

This is the code I'm using:

```
export function fetchMenu() {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(menuRequest(true));
      console.log(Institucion.aplent);
      var response = await fetch('http://<page_url>/api/moviles/personalizacion', {
        compress: true,
        headers: {
          'aplentId' : Institucion.aplent,
          'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate'
        }
      });
      console.log(response);
      if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      var data = await response.json();
      console.log('Data:', data);
      dispatch(menuSuccess(data));
    }
    catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
      dispatch(menuFailure(ex));
    }
  };
}
```

Note: I've changed the url to  for security reasons, but I have the correct url in code.

I've tried with and without the Accept-Encoding header, the same result.

**EDIT**

**If I disable deflate compression inside my REST API (on the server) it works ok, doesn't fetch support deflate compression?**

Comment: You are receiving HTML or XML instead JSON. Have you checked that service you are calling gives back a JSON response?

Comment: Yes. it does, it only return JSON, no other format, I tested it in postman, and return what I expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server side issue, I changed the compression algorithm of the api, and it works well

Comment: if it is not the problem, please remove the question then.

Comment: I think this may be helpful for someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add these headers to the fetch call to ensure you receive JSON:

```
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
```

Comment: Tried with those, same thing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest seeing if it works without explicitly setting compression.

If you don't set the `Accept-encoding` header, react native should automatically zip and unzip it. So probably let it handle it. Instead try changing it to `Accept` header

```
export function fetchMenu() {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(menuRequest(true));
      console.log(Institucion.aplent);
      var response = await fetch('http://<page_url>/api/moviles/personalizacion', {
        headers: {
          'aplentId' : Institucion.aplent,
          'Accept' : 'application/json'
        }
      });
      console.log(response);
      if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      var data = await response.json();
      console.log('Data:', data);
      dispatch(menuSuccess(data));
    }
    catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
      dispatch(menuFailure(ex));
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried without the 'Accept-encoding' header, and as it says in my post, with the same result